# Why I have an SSL certificat error after doing git pull?

Tags: git, ssl-certificate, bitbucket, fatal-error, pull

When I do `git pull` to update my repo, the response is:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/site/site.git/': SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'bitbucket.org'
```

Know that I'm updating my repository always and every day with `git pull`, but today I can't do it. When I've talked with my boss, he said that he changed the repository name on *bitbucket* by just eliminating dashes.

Comment: Git itself is not the problem: Git just uses third-party software to handle SSL/TLS. The problem is in your third-party software, somewhere. For background, see https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/transport-layer-security-tls/ and for your specific problem, start with your host OS: if it's Windows, look up how to update the SSL/TLS software on Windows, if it's MacOS, look up how to update the SSL/TLS software on MacOS, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It usually happens when the certificate does not match with the host name.
As the error code says, "no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name" - so there is an issue with the SSL certificate.

This error occurs for you, because your “boss” has changed the name of the repository (eliminating dashes). So the SSL certificate must be created again before you can do a pull to this repository.

Look at this [tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/securing-bitbucket-server-with-tomcat-using-ssl-776640127.html) or do it the way you created it. But since the name was changed by the repository, the SSL certificate has to be renewed.

Comment: Thank you SwissCodeMen, i've just lost the connection, but i didn't know it because i work with 3 PC. So that's why i had an error like this.

Answer (score 0):

This error appears for me when the Git repo server is behind a VPN and the VPN is down. Check for VPN issues prior to fixing certs or reinstalling TLS/SSL libraries.

Comment: Don't know why this was down-voted - it's true and it just solved me! :D